# Snowflake - Current bind variable substitution

Tags: variables, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, bind

```
delete_cmd  := 'delete from test where rdate='||''':run_date'''||';';
```

The above code is not substituting the date '2022-09-07' assigned to "run_date.

Can you please help with the current substitution?

Comment: What language are you using?  What is the current output?

Answer (score 0):

context helps, so lets write a [Snowflake Scripting block](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/index) that sounds like what you described:

```
declare
  delete_cmd text;
  run_date text;
begin
  run_date := '2022-09-07';
  delete_cmd  := 'delete from test where rdate='||''':run_date'''||';';
  return delete_cmd;
end;
```

and sure enough "it does not work good"

| anonymous block |
| --- |
| delete from test where rdate=':run_date'; |

So looking that code, we see you are concatenating three strings together of which the second is triple quoted, thus a string with an embedded quote mark AND the string tokens `:run_date` as text. so lets drop the triple quotes:

```
  delete_cmd  := 'delete from test where rdate='|| :run_date ||';';
```

now we get:

| anonymous block |
| --- |
| delete from test where rdate=2022-09-07; |

so now the variable is substituted, but the quote is missing.. so we put the embedded quotes in the  string parts (the before and after)

```
  delete_cmd  := 'delete from test where rdate='''|| :run_date ||''';';
```

the output becomes what we are after:

| anonymous block |
| --- |
| delete from test where rdate='2022-09-07'; |

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `$$` to keep things nice and clean

```
declare
  delete_cmd text;
  run_date text;
begin
  run_date := $$'2022-09-07'$$;
  delete_cmd  := $$delete from test where rdate=$$ || :run_date;
  return delete_cmd;
end;
```